# Wordpress Primary Menu colors different in IE, with graphene theme

Tags: menu, themes, css

My website looks different in firefox/chrome when compared to IE

[image: Chrome and Firefox are fine]

ie looks like this , with some weird and ugly blue balck gradient being applied on hover/active state.

[image: IE is picking up some mysterious gradient]

How can I remove the cross browser inconsitency ?

Comment: What is your URL? I have seen this but can't remember the fix. If I could see the problem it might come back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp-content/theme-head.php

Remvoed the follwing line from top-menu colors array

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=\'%1$s\', EndColorStr=\'%2$s\')";
```